# Is there a way to create a table where the number of dimensions is parameterized?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, list-manipulation, functional-style

I'm imagining the likes of this:

```
(* programmatically construct list of N formal params *)

(* somehow curry or bind this list to the first arg of Table[] *)

(* generate data list: {{f1,1,6}, {f2,1,6}, ... {fn,1,6} *)

(* apply my bound Table[] func to my data list, effectively giving:

    Table[{f1,f2,...fn}, {f1,1,6}, {f2,1,6}, ... {fn,1,6}]

*)
```

I'm playing around with a few different constructs, but I can't get anywhere – and I can't seem to describe this question in a search-friendly way.

The point is so I can do some investigation around the PDF and CDF curves you get when throwing N dice.

Comment: Not responsive to the primary question, but to the goal, perhaps you'll find this useful: `die = Table[1/6, {6}];
numberRolled = 3;
totpmf = Transpose[{Range[1*numberRolled, Length@die*numberRolled], 
   Nest[ListConvolve[die, #, {1, -1}, 0] &, die, numberRolled - 1]}]`

Comment: `Tuples` and `Array` might make it simpler than `Table`, depending on what you need precisely. Try `Array[f, {4, 4, 4, 4}]`.

Comment: …and for simulation purposes, this is what `RandomChoice[]` was intended for.

Comment: Thanks folks ... I will read up & play around with these!

Comment: Try also e.g. `n = 2;  m = 4;  fn = #2^2 + #1 &;  Array[fn, Table[m, {n}]]`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out *a* way to do what I was trying to do.

Turns out the graph is not that interesting b/c the scale explodes so quickly.

In anycase, I believe what I have made use of here (the `xx[n]` construct) is an ["indexed object"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html).

```
Manipulate[
 formals = Table[xx[n], {n, 1, a}];
 data = {#, 1, 6} & /@ formals;

 t = Table @@ Prepend[data, formals];

 pdf = Tally[Plus @@@ Flatten[t, a - 1]];
 cdf = Thread@{pdf[[All, 1]], Accumulate[pdf[[All, 2]]]};
 ListPlot[{pdf, cdf}, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> Large]
 , {a, 1, 5, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative take.

```
pdf[n_Integer] := Tally@Flatten@Array[Plus, ConstantArray[6, n]]
Manipulate[ListPlot[pdf[n]], {n, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Performance is significantly improved (10 dice is bearable).

To get the `cdf` add memoization (because bruteforce computation is costly, but end result is simple) and have this:

```
pdf[n_Integer] := (pdf[n] = 
   (Tally@Flatten@Array[Plus, ConstantArray[6, n]])~SortBy~First)
cdf[pdf_] := FoldList[{First@#2, Last@#1 + Last@#2} &, pdf]
```